# Windows XP 64bit Sp2 Installation on Compaq CQ62

Tags: windows-xp, installation, 64-bit, bsod

I have Compaq CQ62-259TU machine (core i5, 4GB DDR3, 500GB HDD), I am trying to install windows XP 64bit SP2 , instead of the windows 7, which is currently install. 
The system boots well from the Windows XP 64bit SP2 CD, but once it reached on "Starting Windows XP Setup", The blue screen error comes up.

I have no idea why its happening, I did some research, some forums said that change in BIOS from SATA to IDE, but I have checked BIOS, there is no such option.

Please any one out there who has successfully installed XP on this machine.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error is " A problem has been detected and windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer. If this is first time you've seen this stop error screen, then restart your computer.if this screen appears again, follow these steps: Check for viruses on your computer. remove any nearly installed hard drive or hard drive controllers. Check your hardrive to make sure  configured"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did you make your HP Recovery discs?, 
>   http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01867124
>
> Make this disc also
>   http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02058933&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

What you can try:

If you wish to keep the functionality of AHCI (SATA) do not set it to IDE in the bios, instead use driver packs to slipstream "Mass storage" drivers into the XP CD.

Driver packs tutorial, read carefully.

http://forum.driverpacks.net/viewtopic.php?id=1449

Download software "Driverpacks Base"

http://driverpacks.net/downloads

You can install other driver packs besides the "Mass Storage", but this will bloat the size of the XP install to DVD size, The only driver packs I suggest to slipstream are

Mass Storage, Chipset, Lan, CPU

This will keep it a size to fit on a CD. If you want all the drivers slipstreamed it will require a DVD burner to make the DVD and a DVD drive on the target installation PC.

I don't change any of the default settings when using the software, just pick the driver packs you want to slipstream and create the ISO image.

If you use other customizing software for other reasons than drivers such as Nlite, use Nlite first then driver packs last or install problems will result. Only use DP to slip drivers, do not use Nlite for this task.

Start with clean unmodified Installation files when using DP for best results

> You may get the same other errors, you are trying to install an OS on hardware and an UEFI bios XP was never meant to be installed on, if you do manage to get it installed, drivers will be a real challenge (impossible) to find for some of that hardware, especially 64bit XP. XP has no clue what a UEFI bios is and never will.